# Getting Email when customers register on checkout page

Tags: email, opencart, mailchimp

I have a little problem in the file success.tpl. I want to display customer email at checkout / success. when they finished register and checkout. so how do I get that customer email at checkout / success or success.tpl?

thank you

Comment: What OpenCart version?

Comment: i use opencar 2.2 sir.

Comment: Do you want to show this email on success page?